# How does this validation.isElementInArray() in AngularJS works?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code, where the if condition used that approach.

```
if( validation.isElementInArray($scope.inputBox, $scope.comments) )
{
$scope.error_msg = " ";
$scope.comments.push($scope.inputBox);
$scope.inputBox = '';
}
 else
{
$scope.error_msg = "Name can't be Same";
}
```

Comment: What is `isElementInArray` ? Is that a custom function?

Comment: Hey, i got it ... actually its a custom service created by source where I got this code for implementation. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Cool. You can also gain some insights on how does it work. I have added an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

`validation.isElementInArray($scope.inputBox, $scope.comments)` works same as you do

```
$scope.comments.indexOf($scope.inputBox) !== -1
```

Which means that the element `$scope.inputBox` exist in `$scope.comments`. Thus, looking at your condition you should be pushing the element in `$scope.comments` when `$scope.inputBox` do not exist in it. So, it should be,

```
 if (!validation.isElementInArray($scope.inputBox, $scope.comments)){
    $scope.error_msg = ' ';
    $scope.comments.push($scope.inputBox);
    $scope.inputBox = '';
  }        
  else {
    $scope.error_msg = 'Name can\'t be Same';
  }
```

Comment: Hey ankit, It works well and I understood well after looking in to your answer. As a beginner to angularjs I have got stuck up with it. Thanks for your post. And keep helping me for further doubts i post.. have a cool day.